# What type of display digital watches use?

Tags: display, 7segmentdisplay

I need a "thin" seven segment display to buy. It should be in size of a digital watch. It can be both seven segment display or character display. How should I search? When I seek for 7 segment display I come across with huge things like lego parts.

Comment: They use LCDs. They are typically custom made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an LCD. Liquid Crystal Display. Scold anyone who says "LCD Display".

Check the [display-modules-lcd-oled-character-and-numeric](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/optoelectronics/display-modules-lcd-oled-character-and-numeric/524437?stock=1) Digikey category.

Comment: Well, sorry. I should've add that I know they are LCDs. But when I look LCD displays on ebay I see 2x16 characters displays always. I want specific type that is small enough for a wrist watch.

Comment: Oh, so this is a shopping question? Did you check the link I shared? When you search for "LCD Displays" you're getting double the display, just do LCD for a single display.

Comment: @Zgrkpnr__ Stop trying to buy components on eBay.

Comment: @Samuel link is helpful indeed. Thank you very much.